# When loading the module mod_proxy_cluster.so in httpd.conf, getting below errors on AIX 7.2 powerpc v1.3.0))

Tags: apache, aix

When loading the module `mod_proxy_cluster.so` in `httpd.conf`, getting below errors on AIX 7.2 powerpc v1.3.0))

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 555 of /opt/freeware/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so into server:

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol proxy_hook_canon_handler was referenced from module
/opt/freeware/lib/httpd/module/mod_proxy_cluster.so(), but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol proxy_hook_pre_request was referenced from module
/opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so(),
but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol proxy_hook_post_request was referenced from module
/opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so(),
but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol ap_proxy_hashfunc was referenced from module 
/opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so(),
but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol ap_proxy_get_balancer was referenced from module
/opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so(),
but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol ap_proxyerror was referenced from module
/opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so(),
but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

rtld: 0712-001 Symbol ap_proxy_canon_netloc was referenced from module
/opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so(),
but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.

Additional errors occurred but are not reported
```

Comment: These symbols are defined in module `mod_proxy.so`: make sure to load `mod_proxy.so` before `mod_proxy_cluster.so`.

Comment: Thank you @Lorinczy Zsigmond
It's working now.